# Passing value to PHP form_open function

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am trying to call the form_open function and pass a value to the function it's calling.  I'm trying to pass the value for $data->advisee_id. Once it calls the setAdvisees function I want it to echo the value.  I've tried a number of things and I'm thinking I might need to pass it into the array which is the second parameter for form open.  Does anyone know how I would do this?  The below code I have currently gives an error when form_open is called stating:

"An Error Was Encountered.  The URI you submitted has disallowed characters."

**eligibletoenroll_view.php**

```
        <?= form_open('app/staff/advisees/setAdvisees($data->advisee_id)', array(
    'class' => 'user-contact',
)) ?>
```

**advisees.php**

```
   function setAdvisees($advisee_id) {
        echo $advisee_id;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just send like this

```
<?= form_open('app/staff/advisees/setAdvisees/$advisee_id)'
```

This sill act as

```
<form action="app/staff/advisees/setAdvisees/$advisee_id"
```

If advise id coming from array then before form open

```
$advisee_id = "some thing"
```

---

**Example**

```
<form action="app/staff/advisees/setAdvisees/25"
```

Comment: hmm it's still giving the error with <form action="app/staff/advisees/setAdvisees/$advisee_id"

Comment: if I set it to <form action="app/staff/advisees/setAdvisees/advisee_id" it works but is showing the wrong advisee_id number

Comment: what you pass it will come to function